# Unable to build SciPy on OS X 10.5.7

Tags: macos, build, scipy

I am trying to install SciPy following these instructions: http://www.scipy.org/Download

And constantly getting error to build them for OS X Lepeord 10.5.7:

dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _iconv_open
  Referenced from: /usr/lib/libaprutil-1.0.dylib
  Expected in: /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _iconv_open
  Referenced from: /usr/lib/libaprutil-1.0.dylib
  Expected in: /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 82, in 
    FULLVERSION += svn_version()
  File "setup.py", line 74, in svn_version
    raise ValueError("Error while parsing svn version ?")
ValueError: Error while parsing svn version ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it absolutely necessary for you to build SciPy from source?  It seems like it would be much easier to install SciPy on Mac OS X Leopard by using the [SciPy Superpack Installer](http://macinscience.org/?page_id=6) (which is mentioned on the [SciPy download page](http://www.scipy.org/Download)). That is how I installed SciPy, and I've never had any problems with it.

Comment: Thanks for providing me the link to Superpack installer ( I hope that it's not similar to MacPorts which played havoc once with my Macbook). That's the reason I opted for building from the source to see what's going on...

I will post the results to my attempt over here!

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's failing is that you have things installed in your /opt/local which are interfering with the system libraries. libiconv is installed in /usr/lib

MacPorts has a habit of messing up things. Unsetting the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH when you run (and when you use) libraries like this would fix it.